# Python skip for loop line if exceed time limit and print skipped line

Tags: python, function, performance, for-loop, time

Similar questions, but a bit different for this use case. I have a function that is run on a number of data frames, I would like a timer to be used as each data frame is running and if takes longer than 30 seconds to skip it and print the data frame names.

function -

```
def some_function():
# runs on pd.DataFrames
    cols = [some code]
    rows = [some code]
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
    return df

df_1 = some_function()
df_2 = some_function()
df_3 = some_function()
```

where `df_1` and `df_2` each take less than 30 seconds, but `df_3` takes 3 minutes. It would then run `df_1` and `df_2`, but print out that `df_3` took longer than 30 seconds. How can I create timed loop like this?

EDIT

loop that organizes data frames in dictionary-

```
def some_function():
# runs on pd.DataFrames
    cols = [some code]
    rows = [some code]
    t1 = datetime.now()
    if (datetime.now()-t1).seconds <=30:
        df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
    return df

d = {}
dfs = range(0,10)
for name in dfs:
    d[name] = some_function()
```

I think this might make it easier, if looping through and taking too long then skip?

Comment: Well, your new edit will stop processing dataframes altogether if the total time goes beyond 30 seconds.  That's not what you originally asked for.  It will not, for example, interrupt a single call that takes to long.  It will just give up after that long call returns.  If that's OK, then go for it.

Comment: I appreciate the comment, but I'm new to this structure and trying to get some help. My intention is the same, I'm just not sure how to do this. Processing each dataframe and seeing if it takes less than 30 secs if so then process, if not then print name

Comment: Then you have to put the time check INSIDE some_function.  You have to take an early exit from that function if the processing goes too long

Comment: How much code is inside `some_function`?  How much can you post?  I know code is sensitive, but the more detail you can provide, the better our advice can be.

Comment: @Tim Roberts I included some snip it of the code in the first block, is basically fetching and organizing rows and cols using a cursor execution into a dataframe

Comment: @Tim Roberts, I've edited the code to reflect what I think you mean..

Comment: Tell you what, I'll post another answer that reorganizes your code a bit.,

Answer (score 1):

Based on the edited question.  The idea here is to check the timeout condition at every point where you've finished something long.

```
def some_function():
# runs on pd.DataFrames
    t1 = datetime.now()
    cols = [some code]
    if (datetime.now()-t1).seconds > 30:
        return None
    rows = [some code]
    if (datetime.now()-t1).seconds > 30:
        return None
    return pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=cols)
```

Comment: for my understanding, why split the ```if (datetime.now()-t1).seconds >30:return None``` into 2 parts?

Comment: It's not split into two parts.  It's checking for timeout twice, first in case the column processing took too much time, second in case adding the row processing took too much time.  You can check the timeout as many times as you need to.

Comment: Note that it's up to the OUTER code to check for the `None` and diagnose it by printing a message.

Comment: it does run but it's not following the timeout check for me.  is it due to the second part of the code? ```d = {}
dfs = range(0,10)
for name in dfs:
    d[name] = some_function()```

Comment: Do you KNOW what parts of the code are taking all the time?  Perhaps you should sprinkle some `print('A:', datetime.now()-t1).seconds)` calls throughout your code.  If, in my example, it was the `pd.DataFrame` call that was taking 90 seconds, then you're screwed.  You can't peek inside that.

Comment: OK it looks like it is ```pd.DataFrame``` then there's nothing I can do to check how long it takes and skip it?

Comment: like something within the ```for name in dfs``` loop?

Comment: No.  You can't know how long it has taken until it's done.  There's no `crystal_ball` module, although heaven knows many have tried.  Now, MAYBE you can compute the length of the columns and rows, and figure out how many is too many before you create the DataFrame...

Comment: OK got it, so I can't calculate run time while it is running and then skip it within loop?

Comment: or if I could track how long the entire loop is calculating and then if longer than 5 minutes end

Comment: No.  While the long function is running, none of your code is running.  There's no way to check.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to add code into some_function() to do this.  Consider, for exaqmple:

```
def some_function():
    timeout = time.time() + 30
    for some_very_large_loop:
        if time.time() > timeout:
            print( "timeout" )
            return None
```

If you have multiple processing loops, just add that clause in each loop.  The outer code will have to check for `None` and print a diagnostic.

Comment: i've made some edits to my post to be more descriptive, I'm quire sure how to apply timeout as you describe here

Comment: could I put ```df_1``` , ```df_2```, etc in the loop and timeout that way?

Comment: using the edit above, a bit more simplified, how could i incorporate the timeout functionality

Comment: You add the timeout check into whichever loops take the most time.  That's the key point.  YOU need to take a manual step to interrupt lengthy operations.  If there is a single pandas operation that takes time, then you can't stop that.

Comment: Ok, but I have a single loop and would like to check which df takes the most time

Comment: If your post doesn't accurately describe your code, then we can't give you meaningful advice.  I've told you how to "early exit" from a function based on time.  If you can organize your code to exploit that, then you're good.

Comment: OK, I have edited a bit further where I'm trying to count each ```df``` taking 30 seconds or less and if not then print the name. Something like this would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

In order to stop execution you would need to work with threads.  If you only want to signal excessive execution time, you can write a decorator that will automate printing of the warning messages:

```
from time import time
def timeLimit(maxTime,name="function"):
    def decorated(f):
        def execute(*arg,**kwarg):
            start    = time()
            result   = f(*arg,**kwarg)
            duration = time()-start
            if duration>maxTime:
                sarg = ",".join(map(str,arg))
                print(f"{name}({sarg}) took more than {maxTime} seconds: {duration}")
            return result
        return execute
    return decorated
```

usage:

```
@timeLimit(2,"myfunction") # max 2 seconds
def myfunction(x):
    for _ in range(x*1000000): pass
    return x*x

result = myfunction(30)
result = myfunction(190)

'myfunction(190) took more than 2 seconds: 3.5628979206085205'
```

Comment: Yes but,. he's interested in abandoning the processing if things are taking too long.  Your solution diagnoses excess time, but doesn't cut things short.  That has to be done cooperatively.